# Algebric troubles while trying to get energy of orbit in isochrone (or plummer) potential

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics, mathematical-astronomy

I am facing this problem, from a [2016 Astrophysics Tripos past paper](https://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/sites/default/files/Papers_1-4_2016.pdf):

---

The gravitational potential

$$\Phi=-\frac{G M}{b+\sqrt{b^{2}+r^{2}}}$$

where $G$, $M$ and $b$ are constants and $r$ is the distance from the origin, is called
the isochrone potential. Show that in the isochrone potential, the energy of a
circular orbit is given by $E=-G M /(2 a)$, where $a=\sqrt{b^{2}+r^{2}}$.

---

(There is [a wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plummer_model) about the potential they are talking about.)

I know that I can express energy of the orbit by

$$E=\frac{1}{2}r\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial r}+\Phi$$

and I have done the algebra resulting in:

\begin{equation}
\tag{got}
\frac{G M\left(\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\bbox[5px,border:2px solid green]{\left(r^{2}+2 b^{2}\right)}\bbox[1px,border:2px solid red]{-b \sqrt{b^{2}+r^{2}}}\right)}{\bbox[5px,border:2px solid green]{\left(r^{2}+2 b^{2}\right)} \sqrt{b^{2}+r^{2}}\bbox[1px,border:2px solid red]{+2 b\left(b^{2}+r^{2}\right)}}
\end{equation}

which numerically does equal

\begin{equation}
\tag{want}
\frac{-GM}{2\sqrt{b^2+r^2}}
\end{equation}

as wanted (checked [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fpvmklwdvg) using Desmos).

I could cancel the terms in green but there are the other terms in red, which I cannot get rid of currently.

How can I go algebraicly from the state I got to the state I want?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8w3wmQAMoxQ

Comment: Thanks :) (I think you might have meant to post this comment to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268817/visually-intriguing-unsolved-problems-which-are-easy-to-explain), but appreciated here too :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We factorize $-\frac12GM$ from the numerator and we factorize $\sqrt{r^2+b^2}$ from the denominator:

\begin{align}
&\frac{GM \left( -\frac12(r^2+2b^2)-b\sqrt{b^2+r^2}\right)}{(r^2+2b^2)\sqrt{b^2+r^2}+2b(b^2+r^2)}\\
&=\frac{-GM}{2\sqrt{b^2+r^2}}\left(\frac{r^2+2b^2+2b\sqrt{b^2+r^2}}{r^2+2b^2+2b\sqrt{b^2+r^2}} \right)\\
&=\frac{-GM}{2\sqrt{b^2+r^2}}
\end{align}