# Visually intriguing unsolved problems which are easy to explain

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics, education, big-list, visualization

I have come across a list of

- visual proofs which are wrong ([Visually deceptive "proofs" which are mathematically wrong](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743067/visually-deceptive-proofs-which-are-mathematically-wrong))
- visual proofs which are not wrong ([Proofs without words](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words))
- visually interesting easy to explain math concepts ([Visually stunning math concepts which are easy to explain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain/1142512))

**I am interested in unsolved or recently solved *problems*, where the question can be summarized well visually & explained easily.**

An example would be the [moving sofa problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_sofa_problem). My easy explanation would be: "draw the biggest sofa which you can maneuver through the corner."

[image]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hammersley_sofa_animated.gif))

**What other examples of visually stunning unsolved problems do you know?**

Comment: "Pivot!"$\quad\quad$

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit? :)